# QGIS Project saved in PostgreSQL not loading on other computers

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have created QGIS projects that are reading from PostgreSQL(data source). I then saved the individual projects to PostgreSQL in the public schema under their respective databases. When I open or load the projects on my machine from PostgreSQL, they open fine without any issue. However, when I open the projects from PostgreSQL on other computers I cannot see them. I cannot see the icon when logged on other computers whether as a superuser (I can only see the rest of the other layers). Also when I log in as a defined user with read-only/view rights I cannot see the projects.

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you checked the "Allow saving/loading QGIS projects in the database" checkbox when you established your PostGIS connection on the other computers?

Comment: Yes, I did check it, made sure it was activated but still does not load.

Comment: @NauwangaNauwanga did you enable the "Allow saving/loading QGIS projects in the database" option on the other users machines (not just yours)? And are the other users running the same version of QGIS as you?

Comment: @DPSSpatial the problem was the difference in the QGIS version. Thank you for pointing me to that direction. I now run into another problem. I connect to the database on the new computer and browse to the schema and can see the QGIS project when I click on it, it asks me for the password, I put in the correct username and passwords which I used before to connect to the database and it says password authentification failed for user "postgres". I am certain I am using the correct password which authenticates on my computer but not on other computers. I am baffled.

Comment: It seems the QGIS project is trying to read the database locally, Realm: dbname:'' host=localhost port 5432 sslmode=disable, then it says, FATAL role "" does not exist, the suggested name of the role is the name of the computer, I tried to create the role on the database but this does not work. My question is can I open QGIS projects on many different computers accessing them from the main database on the server or I first have to have the database hosted locally?

Comment: I tried to put the IP address at the host and resave the project however this does not seem to solve the problem. The idea is to save the QGIS projects and allow different people to view data that are already styled but they should not have the actual database stored locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Fix the data source. Where it says localhost, put the IP address. Do this for every layer, then resave the QGIS project.